# How to create create associative array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Array structure:

```
array(2) {
  ["day"] => array(3) {
    [1] => array(2) {
      ["id"] => int(5)
      ["name"] => string(7) "Example"
    }
    [2] => array(2) {
      ["id"] => int(5)
      ["name"] => string(7) "Example"
    }
    [3] => array(2) {
      ["id"] => int(5)
      ["name"] => string(7) "Example"
    }
  }
  ["day2"] => array(3) {
    [1] => array(2) {
      ["id"] => int(5)
      ["name"] => string(7) "Example"
    }
    [2] => array(2) {
      ["id"] => int(5)
      ["name"] => string(7) "Example"
    }
    [3] => array(2) {
      ["id"] => int(5)
      ["name"] => string(7) "Example"
    }
  }
}
```

I have loop:

```
var i = 1;
            var array = new Array();
            var sub_array = new Array();
            $(".tab-content").find(".excercise-tab-list").each(function(){
                //array.push({tabas: i;})
                    $(this).find(".excercise-tab").each(function(){

                        var svoris = $(this).find('.svoris').val();
                        var kartai = $(this).find('.kartai').val();
                        var id = $(this).find('.ex_id').val();

                        console.log(svoris);
                        console.log(kartai);
                        console.log(id);
                        console.log("----------------- "+i);

                        sub_array.push({svoris: svoris, kartai: kartai});


                    });
                    array.push({diena: sub_array});
                    sub_array = [];

                    i++; 

            });
```

Something is wrong with my code because I not get array like in my example.

Comment: That javascript is not valid: `var array new Array();
    var sub_array();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your use of "sub_array". Once you call it as a function, then you try to push an object to it.